# Unable to show deploy:mode

Tags: magento2

I tried running

```
sudo php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

but I am getting the following error

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant _DIR_ - assumed '_DIR_' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/CustomModule/HelloWorld/registration.php on line 6
```

There are no commands defined in the `deploy:mode` namespace.

Please help I am new to Magento

Comment: There is an issue with constant _DIR_ in your file, please check that.

Comment: Modul.xml file you write some wrong. Check modul.xml file and post xml file...

Comment: module.xml

        
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

         <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org./2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">

 <module name="CustomModule_HelloWorld" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>

Comment: In registration.php replace ```_DIR_``` to ```__DIR__```